# Get Date Taken from Image

Tags: c#, image, date

Is there a better/faster way to get the date taken from an image? this is what I have:

```
//we init this once so that if the function is repeatedly called
//it isn't stressing the garbage man
static Regex r = new Regex(":");

//retrieves the datetime WITHOUT loading the whole image
string[] GetDateTakenFromImage(string path)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (Image myImage = Image.FromStream(fs, false, false))
            {
                PropertyItem propItem = myImage.GetPropertyItem(36867);
                string dateTaken = r.Replace(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(propItem.Value), "-", 2);
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTaken))
                    return null;
                else
                    return DateTime.Parse(dateTaken).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").Split('-');
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How fast do you want it to go and how fast is it now?

Comment: As it seems to work, this is not a valid question here. Maybe CodeReview would be a better fit.

Comment: Filestream is currently the fastest way.

Comment: Actually you are loading the whole image here to get a `PropertyItem`. A faster way is to use a `BinaryReader` to parse the `Exif` content to get the value of `0x132` tag.